# Show that $\cot(5\theta)=\frac{1-10\tan^2(\theta)+5\tan^4(\theta)}{1-10\tan^3(\theta)+5\tan(\theta)}, \forall\theta\in R $

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

Show that 
$$
\cot(5\theta)=\frac{1-10\tan^2(\theta)+5\tan^4(\theta)}{1-10\tan^3(\theta)+5\tan(\theta)},  \forall\theta\in R
$$
using De Moivre's theorem.

Comment: How far have you gotten?

Answer (score 5):

Put $z = 1+i\tan\theta$. Then $\cot(5\theta)$ is the ratio between the real part and the imaginary part of $z^5$:

$$z^5 = (1+i\tan\theta)^5 = 1+5i\tan\theta+10 i^2 \tan^2\theta+10 i^3 \tan^3\theta + 5 i^4 \tan^4\theta + i^5\tan^5\theta,$$

$$z^5 = (1-10\tan^2\theta+5\tan^4\theta) + i(5\tan\theta-10\tan^3\theta+\tan^5\theta),$$

from which the claim follows.

Answer (score 2):

You have already the answer: the Moivre's theorem states that for every integer $n$ and fkr every real $x$ the relation
$$
(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^n=\cos(nx)+i\sin(nx)
$$
Holds.
With $n=5$ and the binomial theorem we have
$$
\cos(5x)+i\sin(5x)=\cos^5(x)+5i\cos^4(x)\sin(x)-10\cos^3(x)\sin^2(x)-10i\cos^2(x)\sin^3(x)+5\cos(x)\sin^4(x)+i\sin^5(x)
$$
Where I have used that $i^2=-1$. Then, factoring out the real and imahinary parts of the left hand side, we arrive at
$$
\cos(5x)=\cos^5(x)-10\cos^3(x)\sin^2(x)+5\cos(x)\sin^4(x)$$
And
$$
\sin(5x)= 5\cos^4(x)\sin(x)-10\cos^2(x)\sin^3(x)+\sin^5(x)
$$
Just use the relations $\cot(5x)=\cos(5x)/\sin(5x)$ and $\tan(x)=1/\cot(x)$ to get your result

Answer (score 1):

Using De Moivre$$(\cos a +i\sin a)^5=\cos 5a +i\sin 5a=$$
$$=\cos^5a+5i\cos^4a\sin a-10\cos^3a\sin^2a-10i\cos^2a\sin^3a+5\cos a\sin^4a-i\sin^5a$$
Real part is$$\cos 5a=\cos^5a-10\cos^3a\sin^2a+5\cos a\sin^4a$$
and imaginary part$$\sin5a=5\cos^4a\sin a-10\cos^2a\sin^3a-\sin^5a$$
from above$$\cot 5a=\frac{\cos5a}{\sin5a}=\frac{\cos^5a-10\cos^3a\sin^2a+5\cos a\sin^4a}{5\cos^4a\sin a-10\cos^2a\sin^3a-\sin^5a}\cdot\frac{1/\cos^5a}{1/\cos^5a}=$$
$$=\frac{1-10\tan^2a+5\tan^4a}{5\tan a-10\tan^3a-\tan^5a}$$

Answer (score 0):

By definition of $\cot{\theta}$ and using Euler's identity, we have:

$$\cot{5\theta} = \frac{\cos{5 \theta}}{\sin{5\theta}} = i \frac{e^{i5\theta} + e^{-i5\theta}}{e^{i5 \theta} - e^{-i 5 \theta}} = i \frac{P+1/P}{P-1/P},$$

where $P = \cos{5\theta} + i \sin{5 \theta} = (\cos\theta + i \sin\theta)^5$ (de Moivre's formula), so it gives:

$$ \cot{5\theta} = i \frac{(\cos\theta + i \sin\theta)^{10} + 1}{(\cos{\theta + i \sin \theta})^{10} -1} $$

I think this yields to the original identity by further simplifications.

Cheers!